# Eclipse/STS does not suggests autocompleting for JUnit code

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

I have a simple project configured with the pom.xml file that I copy below. The problem is that Spring Tool Suite 4.9.0.RELEASE does not suggests automplete for classes nor methods from JUnit library. If I write code like this one:

```
Assert.assertEquals(text_1, text_2);
```

It compiles and works, but if I put the mouse cursor right after the dot after `Assert` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> "No default proposal" message is shown. With other classes out of JUnit autocomplete suggestions works fine.

I checked configuration as proposed in other questions but none fixes this issue.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.microservices</groupId>
<artifactId>Module</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>module</name>
<description>Module tools</description>

<properties>
    <springframework.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>
        ${project.name}
    </finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Probably [one of those content assist glitches](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/showdependencytree.cgi?id=575919&hide_resolved=0) (it's not always, but depends on the surrounding code). Most of them are already fixed in Eclipse 2021-12 (4.22) which will be released tomorrow. Read the [backstory here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=575631#c14).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `.metadata` and `.settings` folders along with `.project` and `.classpath` files seems to have resolved the issue (in addition to reboot Eclipse and import projects again).

This way I also lost launch configurations, etc.

EDIT: As howlger suggests removing `.metadata` folder is serious risk. Do it on you own responsability.

Comment: **Never ever delete the `.metada`** folder**! That's a hoax spread of Stack Overflow that can cause harm. Loosing all non-shared launch configurations is only one thing of it. Use the option `-clean` instead or, if this does not help, create a new workspace. In general, you don't delete files that you don't know what they are for, even if someone on Stack Overflow recommends it.

Comment: I tried `-clean` and many other ways of cleaning and restarting. I saved a copy of `.metadata` folder just in case of errors, but it worked with little loss. I appreciate your advice but I could not find any other solution to my problem.

Comment: People have deleted their `.metadata` folders based on answers like yours and were not happy about the data loss it caused. Deleting the `.metadata` folder instead of using a new workspace is always a bad idea. Again, your answer tells only about loosing launch configurations, but this is only one thing.